# Javascript Function not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following function code in jsp to call a javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:fnUpdate('<s:property value="MstId" />','<%=i%>');">Update</a>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnUpdate(id1,position)
{
    document.forms[0].artpsMstId.value=id1;
    document.forms[0].idNo.value=position;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

Now its working fine in my local machine, but when I deploy the war in production environment, the function is not called, meanss when i click the link, nothing happens. I am using tomacat and both the local and the production environment is same. Would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to solve this...thakns in advance

Comment: Did you try viewing the rendered html coming from your production environment to check if `<%=i%>` outputs what you are expecting?

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: @Raibaz: The <%=i%> is coming as expected

Comment: Can you paste the rendered HTML coming from your prod environment, then, please?